# Android app simple hello world ,run time error help me out

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: You need to install Intel HAXM and enable Intel Virtualization if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Google it and you will get better answers trust me, there are better tutorials showing u each step :)

Answer (score 0):

okay well download the `HAXM` from [Here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) and install it and restart the Android Studio, hopefully it will solve your issue